# Raspberry Pi, Allow Insecure Repositories for Plex Install

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian, plex

I am trying to install Plex media server on my Raspberry Pi 4 via their repo ([details here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-plex-media-server-on-debian-9/)), but come up against the apt-get update command returning the following:

```
E: The repository 'https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb ./public Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

I have tried the following with no luck.

```
sudo apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated
```

I have solved this issue once before, and Plex ran perfectly, but did not take notes and now can't find it again.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=218730 According to this, this is most likely a network issue sometimes while servers are on high load. Try again a few times to see if it works.

Comment: I have tried multiple times with no success. I don't want to use the out of date package specifically Raspberry pi as it is now unsupported, and this has worked before.